# FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error when getContentAsPDF in other org

Tags: pdf

I have 2 org. I developed VF page with *renderAs="pdf"* at first org. And this work correctly. But when I deployed this VF page in other org i see **FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error**. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Might be this is related to [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMLNQA4&title=internal-server-error-while-executing-getcontentaspdf-from-future-context-and-user-have-login-hours-restriction), Pls review workaround mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me when `lightningStylesheets="true"` is present in the `<apex:page>` tag.

The PDF library that Salesforce uses, Flying Saucer, does not play nicely with the CSS used for Lightning. So you'll need to either remove that attribute or set it to "false"

Comment: I haven't `lightningStylesheets="true"`, but i wrote `lightningStylesheets="false"` and this don't help.

Comment: @PavelSemernya Then you'll need to edit your question to include more information. Otherwise, people are just going to be taking shots in the dark. If you have more information about the error message, the Visualforce page you have, whether or not you allowed profiles access to the Visualforce page in the org that you deployed it to (permissions are not deployed with the VF page, nor are permissions for SObject fields being deployed).